# Impossible to change security type after creating Wireless network profile

Tags: c#, windows-10, wifi, wlanapi

I'm willing to let the user to create a dummy Wlan network profile through my windows 10 application and edit it afterwards using windows UI.
I've managed to do so using NativeWifi [WlanSetProfile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706795(v=vs.85).aspx) function with one of those profile Xml [samples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369853(v=vs.85).aspx), but, when I'm opening the windows edit profile UI using the [WlanUIEditProfile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706825(v=vs.85).aspx) function, I can change the security type drop down (from WPA2-Personal to WPA2-Enterprise for example) but when I'm trying to save it (press OK) I'm receiving the following message:

> "Windows has encountered an error saving the wireless profile.
> Specific error: The network connection profile is corrupted."

I'm able to change and save all the other properties besides the security type.

I'll be glad if someone can help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem. 
Now I fix it like this:
In my profile
old settings:
WPA2PSK
AES
and changed to new setings:
WPAPSK
TKIP.

My Win10 version: 1607(OS build 14393.0).